# Logisim Task Bar Issue

Tags: circuit

When I open Logisim on my Windows 10 device, the task bar options are all clumped together and difficult to read(Screenshot tagged in the post). But looks fine on mac.

Screenshot of Left side Task Bar

[image: Screenshot of Left side Task Bar]

Any help would be great.

Comment: I suppose that by "task bar" you mean the project tree view (task bar is another thing). I suspect that you are using a computer with a very high DPI screen so Windows screen scale is configured to 200% or higher. If that is true you are facing with a program that is not properly designed to work with that configuration, I'm afraid that you can't do anything apart from changing your screen configuration (or hoping that the developers fix that).

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> key.

Another possible solution is to hit the Windows button. This tends to bring up the task bar in most programs, for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem off topic, but I'd  create a manifest file for this particular program if it occurs only there. That may solve the problem if done correctly.

Comment: It doesn't occur depending on the file, it's like that no matter what. My screenshot for example is upon start-up of the application.